# Difficulty with RxJS return values and documentation, converting between array and series of items

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm a beginner working through basic examples with RxJS and Angular. I am using:

rxjs 5.5.6
angular 5.2.0

I'm getting the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'do' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
```

from the following code that converts back and forth between an array and a series of items. I am attempting to insert mergeAll in place of mergeMap, which compiles and works as expected in converting the array. I would expect an Observable returned from mergeAll according to the docs without having to cast, especially since mergeMap is based on mergeAll.

```
this.notWorking().subscribe();

notWorking(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.from([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
        .do(obj => console.log(obj))
        // .mergeMap(val => val)
        .mergeAll()
        .do(obj => console.log(obj))
        .toArray()
        .do(obj => console.log(obj))
}
```

In the documentation from ReactiveX RxJS, it shows only a return value of Observable for mergeAll. Am I looking at the right documentation? Am I not understanding something fundamental about RxJS?

> public     mergeAll(concurrent: number): Observable
>
> Converts a higher-order Observable into a first-order Observable which
>   concurrently delivers all values that are emitted on the inner
>   Observables.

[Reactive RxJS mergeAll documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll)

If the case is that it is returning an iterable and this is intended, what is the best practice to chain observable operators? Do I have to cast between each chain or create an Observable? This doesn't make sense to me, I hope I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in typings for `mergeAll` and `concatAll` in RxJS 5.5 that will be fixed in RxJS 6.

For more details see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2759

So the recommended way for now is really using what you did with `.mergeMap(val => val)`.